# Type conversion with leading zeros in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
1.9.3-p551 :016 > 00232.to_i
=> 154 
1.9.3-p551 :017 > 0023.to_i
=> 19 
1.9.3-p551 :024 > 23.to_i
=> 23
```

conversion of number with leading zeros to integer type gives undesirable results. Couldn't able to figure out the reason?. Please advise

Comment: Numbers starting with '0' are considered to be octal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

Comment: It has nothing to do with the conversion – `00232` (without `to_i`) already produces `154`.

Answer (score 4):

Drop the initial zero as it is for representational purpose in Octal numbers.

```
> 00232.to_i
=> 154     # (2 * (8**0)) + (3 * (8**1)) + (2 * (8**2)) + (0 * (8**3))
           # 2 + 24 + 128
           # => 154
```

Similarly for others.

```
> 0023.to_i
=> 19      # (3 * (8**0)) + (2 * (8**1)) + (0 * (8**2))
           # 3 + 16 + 0
           # => 19
```

Comment: Or convert it to a string and add the base:
$> "0023".to_i(10)   # 23
$> "0023.to_i(8)   # 8

Answer (score 0):

Ruby treats the number as octal(base 8) number if it has leading zeros.

To get the decimal number equivalent, convert it to string before converting it to integer.

```
023.to_s(8).to_i
=> 23
```